# A bizarre slot machine

Tags: cipher, pattern, visual, animals

There's a new slot machine in the casino in which you frequently gamble away all of your money!

[image: Slot Machine]

There are heads of animals above each slot... A pig, a parrot that rotates after each spin and a <del>umk</del>rabbit. Maybe the slot machine isn't random and there's a unique pattern for each slot?

CSV Version:

```
Slot 1,Slot 2,Slot 3
UJL,OIC,EJA
ZCQ,CQE,ZHT
LCI,FHJ,PEW
BWI,MQU,QZU
ELC,BJR,RPX
LAG,GWM,TQM
BRS,RXD,WRD
EAS,OAM,UTY
KCY,JHF,XWN
```

### What is the pattern for each slot?

---

<sup>Animal images: http://kenney.nl/assets/animal-pac</sup>

Comment: So Rotter is "weird" and Rotter's Slave is "bizarre"?

Comment: Bounty Edit: I think I know how the first slot works again, so I can add a hint later if no one figures it out :)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @mkinson's answer, finishing the second slot:

> The difference between the last letter of the one slot and the first of the next is 0, 1, 3, 7, ... going forwards (2<sup>n-1</sup>-1).

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer to the second slot:

> Begins with subtracting 6 letters from O to I, then 6 more from I to C. Next it's 12 letters between, then 24, then 48, then 96, etc.